# Restrict se16n to some table rows

Tags: abap, sap-erp

Is it possible to allow an user to view and edit only a subset of all table rows in `se16n`?

I would like to filter on BUKRS and WERKS.

Is this possible by configuring SAP accordingly?

I know that an AUTHORITY-CHECK on 'S_TABU_NAM' is possible. But AFAIK this reveals the whole table.

Comment: There is something called "Line-Oriented Authorizations" (S_TABU_LIN) however I am not sure if it will fully cover your case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should build a custom transaction - SAP has disallowed editing via se16n in most versions. You could maybe still use the FM SE16N_Interface, but put some controls / authority checks in place before calling it